# Is it possible to configure control + scroll-wheel to increase/decrease zoom in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Similar to the default in the Visual Studio editors or Sublime, I would like to use control + scroll-wheel to change the font size / zoom level, rather than control-plus/minus. I did not see any option in the User or Workspace preferences.

Edit from Derek Morin:
If you want this to be the default behaviour, please upvote:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97137

Comment: The current zooming in VSCode is not limited to the editor but all controls. I assume you only want the editor to zoom, but not the rest of the workbench?

Comment: Have you tried Ctr+ and Ctrl- I think its more biased towards editor rather than IDE

Comment: Yes I am using ctrl+/- but was hoping for a scroll-wheel alternative

Comment: This is very deliberately not the default behavior. Some trackpads (such as whatever my Dell comes with) don't have the ability to disable inertia scrolling - I've spent hours to no avail. There is no distinct driver to download for mine. What would happen is I'd scroll the document with two fingers (equivalent to scroll wheel) and THEN hit Ctrl for whatever shortcut I was performing next. This would result in it zooming in or out since the scrollbar was still moving. Insanely annoying. Ctrl + / Ctrl - give much more control anyway.

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851574/zoom-only-text-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> works on US-American layouts. On german keyboard layouts this is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad-0</kbd> which won't exist on a laptop keyboard. A <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>Scroll solution would be very helpful and culture independent.

Answer (score 540, accepted):

You can edit settings.json and add this line:

```
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
```

Or go to settings `CTRL + ,` or `File > Preferences > Settings` and search for:

```
mouseWheelZoom
```

[image]

Comment: @EdSchembor This works when I add this line to the json file but it seems to take away my ability to indent a block of code by highlight lines of code and pressing tab. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How in the name of sweet, almighty God can that not be a default setting?! I get that it's a new tool, still under development but c'mon! I still can't find the option jump-to-next-camel-hump in method names. I like humping camels.

Comment: Working in 1.9.0 (2017-02-02).

Comment: Thank you very much, worked on Version: 1.29.0
Commit: 5f24c93878bd4bc645a4a17c620e2487b11005f9
Date: 2018-11-12T07:42:27.562Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64

Comment: @KonradViltersten I can think of one reason. Many touchpads continue scrolling after you remove your fingers, which is kind of nice, except when you flick to scroll to the bottom of the file, and then press Cmd/Ctrl to initiate some action. VSCode sees the Cmd+scroll and suddenly your code is zoomed to 80pt! I'm experiencing this on a MacBook, so I don't enable the setting there. (I used to experience the same issue in Firefox on Linux, but I think that has been resolved now.)

Comment: @joeytwiddle That happens in all the browsers and many editors (Notepad++ for instance) and, admittedly, it's an annoyance. However, as far I'm concerned, it happens rather rarely and, when it happens, I just scroll back the size. Still, an annoyance, of course. But not having it as default is to take it to far, in my opinion.   :)

Comment: I created an issue to make that the default setting.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97137

Comment: Would be nice to have a similar solution for the integrated terminal, i.e. `terminal.integrated.mouseWheelZoom`. Haven't found anything like that yet :(

Comment: @Nikola That's a surprise. I installed a brand new environment last week including VSCode and the mousy-zoomy thing was there by default. Are you saying that you don't get that behavior out-of-the-box? What OS are you running?

Comment: @KonradViltersten the checkbox was not checked. I have installed vscode approximately ~8 months ago but just started heavily using it. I am running on MacOS

Comment: @Nikola Nope, you're right. I just tested again on a new system and I stand corrected. I forgot that copy over stuff from the cloud into the the *settings.json* file, hence getting all my goodies in one swipe. I guess that whoever made the call on this default option hasn't tried CTRL-wheel (or tried and never understood its greatness). As a side note, I can't imagine why they didn't add the option of storing ones settings in the cloud from the beginning. I guess it's a case of *we learn as we go*.

Comment: This answer also works for zoom buttons on the Logitech mouse.

Comment: The feature request to make it default received less than 20 community upvotes and was closed. I'm glad about that--sorry, Derek. Apple's Magic Mouse tracking speed is too sensitive when set high. The slightest scroll +/- or accidental touch multiplies the zoom level furiously in and out. I keep my tracking speed fast, so reducing speed just for VSCode Mac is not an option for me. I think VSCode Windows does a better job with mouse events, so this is a good candidate for the Windows version until Apple or VSCode improves this.

Comment: First, i like to join the common meaning, WHY THE Fun is that not default setting. Secondly you've just increased my quality of life many times over

Answer (score 81):

in newer versions :

> File -> preferences -> settings -> search for "`mouse wheel zoom`"

Comment: This is the latest and simplest approach!

Answer (score 36):

### `File > Preferences > Settings` and search for:

```
 mouseWheelZoom
```

##### ✅ check this setting

Or,

### go to settings `CTRL + ,`

Or,

### Go the `edit settings.json` and add the below line inside the {parethesis}

```
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
```

#### For reference `setting.json` all preferences

```js
{
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh",
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Cascadia Code', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.largeFileOptimizations": false,
  "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "liveshare.audio.startCallOnShare": true,
  "liveshare.presence": false,
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF",
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "json.maxItemsComputed": 10000,
  "quokka.darkTheme.error.decorationAttachmentRenderOptions": {
    "border": null,
    "borderColor": null,
    "fontStyle": null,
    "fontWeight": null,
    "textDecoration": null,
    "color": "#fe536a",
    "backgroundColor": null,
    "margin": "1.2em",
    "width": null,
    "height": null
  },
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
}
```

Comment: Life is now easier :-)

Answer (score 10):

Is it possible to configure control + scroll-wheel to increase/decrease zoom in VS Code?

Or

Configure Ctrl+ scroll-wheel to increase/decrease zoom in VS Code.

Go to

1 : File > Preferences > Settings

2 : Type "mouseWheelZoom"

3 : select Zoom option :
if you need to zoom on : Ctrl+ Mousewheel (select the check-box)
enter code here
if you Do Not need to zoom on : Ctrl+ Mousewheel (unselect select the check-box)

[Image-1 for: File > Preferences > Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye1Le.png)

[Image-2 for: Type "mouseWheelZoom"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHXuT.png)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Autohotkey you can write a script that presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> when you scroll your mouse up with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> when you scroll your mouse down while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as follows:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

^WheelUp::
Send ^{=}
return

^WheelDown::
Send ^{-}
return
```

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio code :

File -> preferences -> settings -> search for "mouse wheel zoom" then tick the box

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is how VSCode is built, with a [Electron frame](http://electron.atom.io/) and Microsoft Monaco Editor which is built with TypeScript and such web techniques. Therefore VSCode behaves exactly like a browser window would do - zooming the whole application including sidebar etc.

Comment: This is not the case anymore. The rest of the application such as the sidebar and the explorer stay put while zooming the editor with ctrl + mousewheel

Comment: I still miss the tab/file specific zooming that Sublime has. I enjoy VSCode a lot otherwise

Comment: @Brice I thought the same, but VSCode does support separate zooming of the editor and the whole application. For me, CTRL-'+' and CTRL-'-' zoom the whole application, while the scroll wheel only zooms the editor.

Comment: If your VSCode is not configured to have CTRL-'+' and CTRL-'-' zoom the whole UI as it is for @ThePadawan, you can access those commands via _View_ --> _Appearance_ --> _Zoom In_ / _Zoom Out_ / _Reset Zoom_. You can create or modify keyboard shortcuts for these commands via the `workbench.action.zoomIn`, `workbench.action.zoomOut` and `workbench.action.zoomReset` keybindings  in _File_ --> _Preferences_ --> _Keyboard Shortcuts_.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [Zoom only Text in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851574/zoom-only-text-in-visual-studio-code)

On Mac, while pressing the command key, slide two fingers upward to zoom out. Slide downward to zoom in.