# Zoom only Text in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, zooming, usability, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make Vs-code on Mac only zoom the text/file pane of the window? When I hit Command ⌘+ to zoom, it'll zoom all of the window, ie. also the icons on the left hand side and the file pane on the left as well.

Compare these two screen shots, maybe ;)

- [Vs-code window, normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEvX.jpg)
  [image]
- [Vs-code window, zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEvX.jpg)
  [image]

I'd only like the source file (nfsd.sh in the screen shot) to be zoomed.

Answer (score 39):

Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41684631/5295392:

Out of Box solution for zoom in/out for text only:

1. <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd>
2. Type (Open User Settings)
3. Search (Edit settings.json)
4. Add "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
5. Save it.

You can use your mouse wheel to zoom in or zoom out only text in the text box.

Comment: Thank you. I found it from Open User Settings, type "wheel zoom" and check-marked mouse wheel zoom.

Comment: This is great. It helps to be able to zoom in on only the text.

Answer (score 5):

Open your `settings.json` file and increase `editor.fontSize` to increase the size of the text on the source file.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Ctrl + Shift + P`
2. Search 'Zoom'
3. Pick "Editor Font Zoom In"

Repeat till you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, while pressing the command key, slide two fingers upward to zoom out. Slide downward to zoom in.